# How to set a 'div' height same with his neighbor?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using bootstrap as my CSS framework. Now I have some dynamic content in the left side div, and some static content in the right div. I want to the height of right side div auto change base on the height of left side div. Is that possible?

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span5 offset1">
    <div class="well">
      Dynamic Content
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="span5">
    <div class="well" style="height: 330px; overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: scroll;">
      Static Content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes. Could you post the code you have? (or better, make a jsFiddle)

Comment: it could be done with jquery...

Comment: what if the static content is bigger then the dynamic? you want it to scroll? or the dynamic height should grow?

Comment: @avrahamcool if the static content is bigger than the dynamic he can just set the min-height of the dynamic equal to the height of the static. Problem solved :)

Comment: I asked what behavior **he** wants..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think jQuery is the best solution to achieve this. Check out my fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/PHjtJ/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var dynamic = $('.dynamic');
    var static = $('.static');

    static.height(dynamic.height());

});
```

Answer (score 8):

You could do [this](http://jsfiddle.net/chopper/LF3Un/2/)

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="dynamic">
        Dynamic Line <br />
        Dynamic Line <br />      
        Dynamic Line <br />
        Dynamic Line <br />      
        Dynamic Line <br />
        Dynamic Line <br />      
        Dynamic Line <br />
        Dynamic Line <br />      
    </div>
    <div class="static">
        Static<br />
        Static<br />        
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
    overflow: auto;
}

.dynamic {
    position: relative;
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 200px;
}

.static {
    position: absolute;    
    background-color: orange;
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
    left: 200px;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}
```

Comment: A complication could be if the right side has more lines than the left. One way around this could be to specify a `min-height` on the `.wrapper` ([see here](http://jsfiddle.net/chopper/LF3Un/3/)). Not sure if there's a better pure CSS solution. There's always jQuery though.

Comment: Add `overflow-y: scroll` to your static class. [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/LF3Un/5/).

Comment: Yes, that's an option. However it depends on the use case.

Comment: Ah I see. Good point. In that case adding `min-height: 330px` in combination with `overflow-y: scroll` should give the desired result.

Answer (score 2):

the solution depends on the behavior you want in the case where the `static` column is larger than the `dynamic` one. [I actually think you want the second scenario.]

Notice: both case are pure CSS, and without specifying any height whatsoever.
also, not specifying a margin of any sort, so you can change the width of the column at your will, without the need to calculate the margin/position again and again..

1. if you want the dynamic column to enlarge, and to be as the static height:
   so you actually want the columns to always be a the same height.
   and that can be easily achieved with CSS table layout styling.
   in that case: See this [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/dJTVH/2/) (the script is only for adding dynamic content, this is a pure CSS SOLUTION)
2. if you want the dynamic column to stretch only to its content height, and the static one to have the same height + a scroller.
   in that case: see this [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/dJTVH/4/) (again: the script is only for adding dynamic content, this is a pure CSS SOLUTION)

in both cases, the static column grows if the dynamic one become longer.

Answer (score 2):

Use Javascript/jQuery to find which box has the biggest height. Then set the same height to all the divs.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        var description = jQuery("div.description");
        var big =0;
        description.each(function(index, el) {
            if(jQuery(el).height() > big)
                big =jQuery(el).height(); //find the largest height
        });

        description.each(function(index, el) {
            jQuery(el).css("min-height", big+"px"); //assign largest height to all the divs
        });
    });
</script>
```