# Align boxes without using columns

Tags: html, css

I have this `HTML` structure:

```
<div class="box_holder">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box" style="height: 220px;background-color: black;"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

And this is my `CSS` (basically):

```
.box_holder {
    width: 440px;
}
.clear { clear:both;}
.box {
    width:200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 10px;
    float: left;
    background: red;
}
```

Link to JSFiddle with the code above: http://jsfiddle.net/9YSDG/

I'm trying to remove the space I've marked with a green arrow:
[image]

This space is showing when my `div.box`-es are with different heights. I think I have to separate the boxes in two different `div`s (one with `float: left;`, the other with `float: right`) but can this way be avoided, since the data that is coming from the backend generates this html content as the layout in the fiddle?

**Edit**: The content of the boxes is text with different length. And if I use equal height the data will not display in a nice way, because some of the `div`s may have one sentence others may have 4 or something like that.

Comment: You can use Equal height for this

Comment: @YogeshSharma I've edit my question. Explaining why equal height doesn't work for me.

Comment: Does this help you?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18940591/how-to-set-a-div-height-same-with-his-neighbor

Comment: http://codepen.io/imohkay/pen/gpard

Comment: Take a look at Masonry, http://masonry.desandro.com/, for a JavaScript solution or if you don't need deep browser support you can use CSS columns, http://osvaldas.info/examples/responsive-pinterest-style-layout-with-css/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd either need to use JavaScript, or a JavaScript plugin like masonry, to calculate the div heights and adjust them to fix the gap, or just change the CSS slightly. Instead of floating all the divs left, alternate them:

```
<div class="box_holder">
    <div class="box l"></div>
    <div class="box r"></div>
    <div class="box l"></div>
    <div class="box r" style="height: 220px"></div>
    <div class="box l"></div>
    <div class="box r"></div>
    <div class="box l"></div>
    <div class="box r"></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
.l {
    float: left;
}
.r {
    float: right;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/HK8L6/)**

Comment: +1 loving the alternate approach! did some refactoring: http://jsfiddle.net/coma/fLJm5/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can do a negative margin-bottom class.

```
.oddball {
    margin-bottom: -10px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Hunter275/9YSDG/3/

Answer (score 0):

I updated your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/raffi/9YSDG/5/

Just add this jQuery code:

```
var boxes = $('.box');
var max_height = 0;
var height = 0;
boxes.each(function() {
    height = $(this).height();
    if(height > max_height) {
       max_height = height;
    }
});
boxes.css('height', max_height);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `vertical-align: bottom;` to your **.box**

Comment: I don't think `vertical-align: bottom;` does what you think it does, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align.